# Matrix Factorization and Overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, recommender-system

I recently came accross the algorithm of Matrix Factorization for a recommendations system.

One of the tutorials I followed can be found  [here](http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/).

According to it given the initial matrix $R$ and the goal to factor it into two matrices $P$ and $Q$ with $k$ latent features the error for each known entry is calculated using the following formula **in order to avoid overfitting** :

$$e_{ij}^2 = (r_{ij} - \sum_{k=1}^K{p_{ik}q_{kj}})^2 + \frac{\beta}{2} \sum_{k=1}^K{(||P||^2 + ||Q||^2)}$$

What I don't understand is :

- Why add the $\frac{\beta}{2} \sum_{k=1}^K{(||P||^2 + ||Q||^2)}$ part to the squared error? It seems a bit arbitrary
- How does it prevent overfitting?

Comment: The basic idea is that constraining the solution to have smaller magnitude weights gives us a dial that we can turn up or down control the extent of any overfitting. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188092/why-do-smaller-weights-result-in-simpler-models-in-regularization

Answer (score 1):

The idea prevalent in recommender systems is to find a low rank approximation of your matrix. The matrix factorization you describe gives rise to a low-rank approximation (at least when $k$ is relatively little of course...) . From [this paper](http://humansensing.cs.cmu.edu/sites/default/files/nuclear.pdf) (and references therein) you can learn of the different steps leading to this $||P||^2 + ||Q||^2$ regularization. It comes as an equivalent form of the nuclear norm, which is a convex surrogate of the rank (in fact its [convex envelope](https://angms.science/doc/LA/NuclearNorm_cvxEnv_rank.pdf) on bounded matrices). To help you further, you can note [this other reference](http://www.vision.jhu.edu/teaching/learning/deeplearning19/assets/soln-hw1-deeplearning19.pdf), which gives a proof (Lemma 1)